# Is there any app that i can upload images instantly from phone to computer?

Tags: photo

Chrismas is coming,I am so excited caz I will go to Maldives.the thing is I don't want to take my computer with me,and I am sure that I will take many photoes.Is there any app that I can just share my images to computer without using USB?Thx!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Internet connection, the Dropbox works well, as do others like SugarSync.

If you don't, then there is this app:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wireless-transfer-app/id543119010

That transfers via WiFi (I have nothing to do with this company by the way)

I'm sure there are plenty of other bluetooth or WiFi capable transfer apps available on the App Store that'd help.

(Finally, if you do have Internet access, and both a recent iPhone and version of iOS) there is also Apple's own Photo Stream, which works using iCloud.)

Comment: read question carefully, it talks about FTP

Comment: I did read the question carefully. There's no mention of ftp. There's only an ftp tag. For safety, I've covered all the bases in case the OP wanted that level of coverage.

Answer (score 0):

use dropbox? you can put the images on dropbox and then see it on de the computer inmediatly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Yaroslav - how on earth does "use dropbox" not answer the question "is there any app that I can just share my images to my computer without using USB?"

Comment: You are right. I incorrectly selected the flag, is just that the question was not SO compliant and I missread.

Answer (score 0):

[DropBox for Android/iOS](https://www.dropbox.com/)

`DropBox` is what you need, you haven’t specified what phone do you have but DropBox apps do come in for `Android` and `iOS` *(I’m not sure about others)*.

You synch you gallery, camera upload or any other folder you like with it and it will keep uploading your pictures documents automatically to your DropBox folder in your computer,all you need is an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try Dropbox.

Install it on your computer and then on your android/apple/windows8 phone and it will give you the option to automatically upload phone pictures to your dropbox folder. You can then find them on you computer in the folder dropbox creates.

Answer (score 0):

`xCloud` is recommended, which is an app to remotely control your pc and manage your files, or even without network.